# Find slope at (4,2) and equation of tangent line

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry

given 
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x}, p = (4,2)$$

The formula for the slope is $$\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Which gives me
$$\frac{\sqrt{4-h}-\sqrt{4}}{h}$$
which gives me 
$$\frac{\sqrt{4-h}-2}{h}$$

I know m = 1/4 but I'm not sure how to get there from my last step.  Once I know the slope the rest is not difficult.

Comment: Actually, you have to calculate the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(4 + h) - f(4)}{h}$, or equivalently $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{f(x) - f(4)}{x - 4}$.

Comment: @Allawonder that's fine, but he'll get a negative answer

Comment: @Allawonder He will obtain $- 1/4$ as the result, which is obviously not the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the slope formula, you should actually have $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{h}$.

Now, let's make $h$ super small, and this value should approach the slope of the tangent line.

We have $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{h} = \frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}{h} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{4+h}+2}{\sqrt{4+h}+2}=\frac{(4+h)-2^2}{h(\sqrt{4+h}+2)}=\frac{h}{h(\sqrt{4+h}+2)}$.

Now, this is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{4+h}+2} $. We see that as $h$ grows small, the slope should approach $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}+2}=\frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: Thank you, I had been trying to multiply the top and bottom by $\sqrt{4+h}\ and not the entire numerator which now makes sense why I wasn't getting 1/4

Comment: Ah. In general, when you're conjugating, let's say 1/(a+bi) or 1/(a+√b), you need to conjugate the whole thing, because you're aiming for something to become a^2-b^2 which eliminates said square roots or imaginary etc.

Comment: thanks, I had f(x+h) on my paper but wrote it here as f(x-h) on accident

Comment: @dstarh you can still work with that, but the denominator should be -h then, because you have (2-h)-2 = -h

Answer (score 1):

What you've calculated is the opposite of the slope of the chord defined by the points $(4,2)$ and $(4-h,\sqrt{4-h})$.

The slope of the tangent line at a point on a (differentiable) curve is simply the value of the derivative at this point, so 
$$m=\frac 1{2\sqrt x}\Biggr|_{x=4}=\frac14.$$

As to the equation of the tangent line, you have a formula for that:
$$y-f(x_0)=f'(x_0)(x-x_0).$$

*Added* (as the O.P. hasn't seen derivatives yet):

The tangent line at $(4,2)$ is the limiting position of a chord through this point and another point $(4-h,\sqrt{4-h})$ when the latter tends to $(4,2)$, i.e. when $h$ tends to $0$.  So to obtain the slope  of the tangent, we need to determine the limit of the slopes of the chords:
$$\frac{\sqrt{4+h}-2}h, \quad\text{or, if you prefer},\quad \frac{\sqrt{4-h}-2}{-h}.$$
To obtain the limit, we use the trick of the *conjugate expression* to rationalise the numerator:
$$\frac{\sqrt{4-h}-2}{-h}=\frac{(\sqrt{4-h}-2)(\sqrt{4-h}+2)}{-h(\sqrt{4-h}+2)}=\frac{\not4-h-\not4}{-h(\sqrt{4-h}+2)}=\frac{1}{(\sqrt{4-h}+2)},$$
which tends to $\;\frac1{\sqrt{4\,}+2}=\frac14$.

Comment: We've not covered derivatives yet which likely would have made this easier

Comment: How do you define the tangent line, then?

Comment: good answer but how would OP know that sqrt(x) --> 1/2sqrtx

Comment: In the O.P., nothing was mentioned about knowing or not about derivatives.

Comment: @Bernard if I don't know what a derivative is, nor how to solve it, I wouldn't know it could be used to solve this which is why I didn't mention not knowing it.

Comment: Please see if my update makes things clearer.